# Correctly using C++20 `[likely]]`/`[[unlikely]]` in `switch` statements

Tags: c++, attributes, switch-statement, c++20, branch-prediction

C++20 has handy `[[likely]]`/`[[unlikely]]` attributes which guide code generation.  For example, you can specify a branch is likely to be taken by:

```
if (b) [[likely]] { /*...*/ }
```

Similarly, it is possible to use these attributes in `switch` statements . . . somehow?  [The documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/likely) suggests the following example (slightly formatted):

```cpp
switch (i) {
    case 1:
        [[fallthrough]];
    [[likely]] case 2:
        return 1;
}
```

The implication is clearly that the `[[likely]]`/`[[unlikely]]` goes before the `case` statement.  The internet seems to almost universally promulgate this usage.

However, consider the following similar code (all I've done is move the `[[likely]]` to the other `case`):

```cpp
switch (i) {
    [[likely]] case 1:
        [[fallthrough]];
    case 2:
        return 1;
}
```

This fails to compile on clang!  While that may be related to [a compiler bug with `[[fallthrough]]`](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49454), it got me looking at the standards.  The [relevant standard](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0479r2.html) has the following example (see §VII):

> implementations are encouraged to optimize for that case being executed (eg. a having the value 1 in the following code):

```cpp
switch (a) {
    case 1: [[likely]]
        foo();
        break;
    //...
}
```

That is, the attribute comes *after* the case label, not before.

So . . . which is it?  Offhand, I'd expect the standard to be correct, but that is actually a proposal, not the real standard AFAICT—it could have been changed since.  And, I'd expect the documentation, if nothing else, to be correct at least about the fundamental syntax—except that it doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both examples are valid, and Clang is exhibiting a bug. The relevant verbiage from the last standard draft for C++20 is

> **[dcl.attr.likelihood]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.attr.likelihood#1.sentence-1) The attribute-tokens `likely` and `unlikely` may be applied to labels or statements.

Where the relevant grammar productions for statements and labeled statements have an attribute specifier sequence at the appropriate locations.

> **[stmt.pre]**
>
> ```
> statement:
>   labeled-statement
>   attribute-specifier-seq expression-statement
>   attribute-specifier-seq compound-statement
>   attribute-specifier-seq selection-statement
>   attribute-specifier-seq iteration-statement
>   attribute-specifier-seq jump-statement
>   declaration-statement
>   attribute-specifier-seq try-block
> ```
>
> **[stmt.label]**
>
> ```
> labeled-statement:
>   attribute-specifier-seq identifier : statement
>   attribute-specifier-seq case constant-expression : statement
>   attribute-specifier-seq default : statement
> ```

In

```
switch (i) {
    case 1:
        [[fallthrough]];
    [[likely]] case 2:
        return 1;
}
```

The attribute applies to `case 2:` wheras in

```
switch (a) {
    case 1: [[likely]]
        foo();
        break;
    //...
}
```

it applies to the statement `foo();`.

Comment: While brevity is nice, I feel like the language grammar rules are highly relevant here. Also, I'm having a hard time seeing a difference between `[[likely]]` applying to `foo();` vs. to the `case` statement, since (outside of fallthrough or `goto`) the `case` statement is the only way `foo();` could be reached. Sure, I can see `[[likely]] foo();` working as an isolated construct, but the paper did explicitly say this affects the `case` . . .

Comment: @imallett - It *said* it should affect the case (not goto labels however), but the normative *wording* proposed there only mentions statements. Nor does the proposal touch upon the required grammar changes. The standard contains more refined wording. And you see no difference because there is none. The normative wording is simply designed to allow more flexible placement.